# Filter Listview by items and dividers

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile, filtering, divider

In jQueryMobile, I have written a `data-role="listview"` component and I want to filter the data including its dividers. That is, when the user inputs some text to search, it may correspond to specific items or to dividers. In this last case, the whole divider and its subitems must be shown. The problem is that the default filtering mechanism ommits the dividers and I don't know how to properly redefine the `filterCallback` function.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

The code which I was trying is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DCkDp/).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your example works for me, pressed 'b' and the 'aaaa' divider was removed

Comment: That's because the second divider includes an element which contains the letter 'b', but not because the divider text includes that letter. Try to search for 'bbbb'. I would like that the divider would appear in this case.

Comment: Could I ask why you need this? The divider is used to group not display a result IMHO

Comment: Well it's a start: http://jsfiddle.net/DCkDp/2/ not fully working but might give you an idea

Comment: The truth is that it's only for private interest, but who knows... maybe 'AAAA', 'BBBB' could be really 'Sales', 'Marketing' or other department names where some people work :) Thanks for your approximation

Comment: By the way, doing http://jsfiddle.net/DCkDp/5/ I get only the dividers. Now I need to figure the way to get also all the elements inside them...

Comment: I understand now, you want to show all options for a divider? right?

Comment: That's right. If I searched for 'AAAA', I would like to show the divider 'AAAA' and all the items included in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I have something:

- http://jsfiddle.net/DCkDp/24/

JS

```
$("#myList").listview('option', 'filterCallback', function (text, searchValue) { 
    $("li[data-groupoptions]").removeClass('override-ui-screen-hidden');
    $("li[data-groupoptions="+searchValue.toLowerCase()+"]").addClass('override-ui-screen-hidden');
    return text.toLowerCase().indexOf( searchValue ) === -1;
});
```

CSS

```
.override-ui-screen-hidden {
    display:block !important;   
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="myList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-groupoptions="aaaa">AAAA</li>
            <li data-groupoptions="aaaa"><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
            <li data-groupoptions="aaaa"><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
            <li data-groupoptions="aaaa"><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-groupoptions="bbbb">BBBB</li>
            <li data-groupoptions="bbbb"><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
            <li data-role="list-divider" data-groupoptions="cccc">CCCC</li>
            <li data-groupoptions="cccc"><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
            <li data-groupoptions="cccc"><a href="index.html">Christopher Adams</a></li>
            <li data-groupoptions="cccc"><a href="index.html">Culver James</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only made a small change and instead of selector `$("li[data-groupoptions="+searchValue.toLowerCase()+"]")` I used `$("li[data-groupoptions*="+searchValue.toLowerCase()+"]")` so the specific group will also appear when searching for a part of its name. Updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/DCkDp/25/

Comment: Even better +1 for a nice out of the box question. At first I didn't understand the practical application but now I really like it

Comment: The only problem I see, that it's not generic, so it won't play nice with KnockoutJS out of the box

Comment: Uh, oh, you can do a regex search, rather than computing all lower case!

Answer (score 3):

For including results matching dividers text, I put in each lines a hidden p  wich contains the divider's text.

```
<li>
    <a>
        <p>Item</p>
        <p style='display:none;'><?php echo $my_divider; ?></p>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little improvement over Phill Pafford answer to match incomplete dividers names:
change this:

```
$("li[data-groupoptions="+searchValue.toLowerCase()+"]").addClass('override-ui-screen-hidden');
```

with this:

```
$("li[data-groupoptions*="+searchValue.toLowerCase()+"]").addClass('override-ui-screen-hidden');
```

Now you can match 'AAAA' just typing 'AA'.  Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qjJw3/